# sbcl - why not execute code in sequence

Tags: io, common-lisp, sbcl, clisp

I'm excising example from book: ANSI Common Lisp, charpter 14.6 conditions.

sbcl not print the prompt in correct order:

example code:

```
(defun user-input (prompt)
    (format t prompt)
    (let ((str (read-line)))
      (or (ignore-errors (read-from-string str))
      nil)))
```

In sbcl test, the prompt will not print in order:

```
* (defun user-input (prompt)
    (format t prompt)
    (let ((str (read-line)))
      (or (ignore-errors (read-from-string str))
      nil)))

STYLE-WARNING: redefining COMMON-LISP-USER::USER-INPUT in DEFUN

USER-INPUT
* (user-input "Please type an expression> ")
test
Please type an expression> 
TEST
* (user-input "Please type an expression> ")
#%@#+!!
Please type an expression> 
NIL
*
```

But in clisp, the prompt is printed in order and it works as expected:

```
[5]> (defun user-input (prompt)
    (format t prompt)
    (let ((str (read-line)))
      (or (ignore-errors (read-from-string str))
You are in the top-level Read-Eval-Print loop.
Help (abbreviated :h) = this list
Use the usual editing capabilities.
(quit) or (exit) leaves CLISP.
  nil)))
USER-INPUT
[6]> (user-input "Please type an expression> ")
Please type an expression> #%@#+!!
NIL
[7]>
```

Comment: Output is buffered in SBCL. see the functions force-output and finish-output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert [`force-output`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm) after
`format` in your `user-input` to avoid i/o buffering issues:
normally, nothing is actually printed to the device until a newline or
`force-output` or `finish-output`.